# modify html file in .net windows app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, google-maps, webbrowser-control, html-editor, windows

I have a map.html file that contains a script for google maps api v3, i've been trying previously trying to run this script using the webbrowser1.DocumentText and Webbrower1.Document.InvokeScript been unsuccessful.

This time i have the map.html hosted on a website, My objective is been able to modify this html file and then run it on my windows application in order to display a desired address.

below is the code of the map.html which is hosted ex: http://url.com/map.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com.mx/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=es"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var geocoder;
    var map;


    function initialize() {

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        //var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            //center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        //var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        var address = "Miami Beach, Flordia" //Address to modify in order to display

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

if you copy and paste this code in a html it should display Miami Beach, FL

now on my windows application i want to edit this html that is hosted on a website i want to change Miami Beach, Florida to Naples,Florida as an example.

then use a webbrowser on my windows application and display it as Webbrowser1.Navigate("http://url.com/map.html")

your help is very appreciated it.

I did found how to modify an html when it is saved locally on my computer but for what i exactly need this is not a viable way.

thank you,

Leo P.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to modify the html code. Since the Google Maps code is all JS, I would write a JS function to move the map to the new location.
You can call that function from your application (or even insert it from there).

```
using mshtml;

//First, navigate to your page:
Webbrowser1.Navigate("http://url.com/map.html")


void Webbrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        //Then call your move function with the new target:
        mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)Webbrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
        mshtml.IHTMLWindow2 window = (mshtml.IHTMLWindow2)doc.parentWindow;
        window.execScript("yourMapMoveFunction('Naples,Florida');");
}
```

BTW, your link does not show a map...

Comment: someone helped me solve this on another post, in which i was actually trying to run the whole script on webbrowser. his solution also applies to this question. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705729/net-windows-application-webbrowser-google-maps-api-v3" thank you so much for your help !